# how to use Guid as an attribute constructor value or object in a custom ValidationAttribute

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core

I need to pass a *Guid* value to a custom ValidationAttribute, but I get

> Attribute constructor parameter 'siteUId' has type Guid, which is not
>   a valid attribute parameter type

If I change Guid to *object* I get

> An attribute argument must be of a constant expression, typeof
>   expression or array expression of an attribute parameter type

**Validator**:

```
public sealed class ViewNameAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly Guid _siteUId;

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if a view with the same name exists
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="siteUId">UId of site which to add view</param>
    public ViewNameAttribute(Guid siteUId)
    {
        _siteUId = siteUId;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        ISitesRepo repo = validationContext.GetRequiredService<ISitesRepo>();
        ISite site = repo.GetSite(this.SiteUId).Result;
        IStringLocalizer<ValidationResources> localizer = validationContext.GetRequiredService<IStringLocalizer<ValidationResources>>();
        string name = value.ToString();
        var tmp = site.Views.SingleOrDefault(vw => vw.Active && vw.Name.ToUpper() == name.ToUpper());

        if (!tmp.IsNull())
        {
            return new ValidationResult(localizer["SitesViewNameExists"].Value);
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    private Guid SiteUId => _siteUId;
}
```

**Model**:

```
public interface ICreateViewModel
{
    string GroupName { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CreateViewModel : ICreateViewModel
{
    [FromRoute(Name = "site")]
    public static Guid SiteUId { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(IStringLocalizer<ValidationResources>), ErrorMessageResourceName = "SitesNewViewNameMissing")]
    [MinLength(6, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(IStringLocalizer<ValidationResources>), ErrorMessageResourceName = "SitesNewViewNameToShort")]
    [ViewName(SiteUId)]
    [FromForm(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem as well in the past. The only way I got it to work was to pass the value as a string. Simply because the parameters have to be a constant. And a guid cannot be a constant because it is an object held by reference.

This has been asked on stackoverflow before, which sadly confirms my suspicion that it is not possible.

[How do I take a GUID as an attribute parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325756/how-do-i-take-a-guid-as-an-attribute-parameter)

```
public class ViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string PropertyOne { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ViewName("dec070c6-c25f-4e9d-a003-17ce72b74a94")]
    public string PropertyTwo { get; set; }
}

public sealed class ViewNameAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly Guid _siteUId;

    public ViewNameAttribute(string siteUId)
    {
        _siteUId = Guid.Parse(siteUId);
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I ended up reading it from validationContext.ObjectIntance. Not ideal, but it works